# Sessions being cleared when reaching the Review page in Ubercart

Tags: php, apache, drupal, nginx, ubercart

Experiencing an issue with an Ubercart 2 store that is now running on nginx.

Authenticated users can checkout and order products without an issue.

Anonymous users can put items in the cart, and when they hit the Review Order page, all the information is cleared out.

Boost is also enabled but ignoring the Store section of the website. Memcache is also enabled. SecurePages is directing users to secure connection as soon as any store page is visited.

Any ideas on why this is happening? Everything worked fine until we implemented nginx and reverse proxies for the website to handle additional traffic. No Drupal configuration has changed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Which version of Ubercart are you using?  There is an issue with the current version.  I actually created a patch for it, but there are a few issues.

Here is the one I made... http://drupal.org/node/862348

It later got merged into this one... http://drupal.org/node/858816

It's still up for debate, but one thing you can try (if you can) is to rollback to the version right before the current one, as the current one is the one that broke.

Comment: It is a version from February of this year I believe

Comment: Ok. Do you know what version number it is?  You can go to the "Available Updates" page to get the version you're using.